# How to create item without passing id from angular app to firestore with ngrx/entity?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I am trying to perform a full CRUD operation using Angular + Cloud Firestore + NGRX/Entity.

Id is required parameter to perform ngrx/entity. But when I create an item from my angular form to my firestore, I don't know yet the id as it would be assigned automatically with the document id of my future creation.

How can I send data to firestore using ngrx/entity without sending the id?

I have an interface as follow:

Interface of entity:

```
export interface Recipe {
    id: string;
    recipeTitle: string;
}
```

actions.ts:

```
export const addRecipe = createAction(
    '[Recipe Add Component] Add Recipe',
    props<{ recipe: Recipe }>()
);

export const addRecipeSuccess = createAction(
    '[Recipe Add Effect] Add Recipe Success',
    props<{ recipe: Recipe }>()
);

export const addRecipeFailure = createAction(
    '[Recipe Add Effect] Add Recipe Failure',
    props<{ error: any }>()
);
```

Reducer.ts

```
// entity adapter
export const recipeAdapter: EntityAdapter<Recipe> = createEntityAdapter<Recipe>({
});

export interface RecipeState extends EntityState<Recipe> {
  error: any;
  selectedRecipe: Recipe;
}

export const initialState: RecipeState = recipeAdapter.getInitialState({
  error: undefined,
  selectedRecipe: undefined
});

export const recipeReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

  on(RecipeActions.addRecipeSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return recipeAdapter.addOne(action.recipe, state);
  }),
  on(RecipeActions.addRecipeFailure, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: action.error
    };
  }),
```

Effects.ts

```
  createRecipe$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(fromRecipeActions.addRecipe),
            mergeMap(action =>
                this.recipeService.createRecipe(action.recipe).pipe(
                    map(recipe => fromRecipeActions.addRecipeSuccess({recipe})),
                    catchError(error =>
                        of(fromRecipeActions.addRecipeFailure({ error }))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Create Component.ts

```
  createRecipe(formGroup): void {
    const recipeCreated = {
      recipeTitle: formGroup.recipeTitle
    };
    this.store.dispatch(actions.addRecipe({recipe: recipeCreated}));
    this.router.navigate(['tabs/recipe']);
  }
```

service.ts

```
 createRecipe(recipe): Observable<any> {
      return from(this.firestore.collection(`recipes`).add(recipe));
  }


  getRecipes(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.firestore.collection<Recipe>('recipes').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(arr => {
      return arr.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.payload.doc.data();
        return {
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
          ...data
        } as Recipe;
    });
  }));
}


  deleteRecipe(recipeId: string) {
    return from(this.firestore.collection<Recipe>('recipes/').doc(recipeId).delete());

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom ID selector which would make id optional:

```
export const recipeAdapter: EntityAdapter<Recipe> = createEntityAdapter<Recipe>({
   selectId: t => t.id || 0
});
```

Comment: I tried to add that line in my reducer.ts 
the ' || 0'  is complaining since my id is a string.

Then I change the type of id to make it number. 

But my create function is still complaining that id is missing on type Recipe. 

Should I add something in my effect or my createRecipe() ?

Comment: did you make id nullable inside of the Recipe class? i.e. export class Recipe { id?: number }